# desktop application from the webbrowser

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, desktop-application

I have a desktop application that takes few input parameters and give me the resultant output file.

I want to use via web. I want to create a website where user can input those parameters and then i can process it on my server (using the desktop application) and display the resultant file to the user

Answer (score 0):

You can call your application from a site using [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

[`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) will let you to return a file to the browser.

It is not clear from your question where you are having difficulties. Can you be more specific?

Comment: My desktop application draw sketches after getting some parameters and later i use them to draw characters in my browser.

Comment: Whenever a new user register on the web, according to his profile i want to create the sketch using that desktop application and then use those sketches in the browser fro characters animation etc.

Comment: Can you please more elaborate your answer, with 'Process.Start' I can start the process but how to pass the parameters to that desktop application

Comment: @Muhammad - Did you check the links I added? There are examples there.

Comment: @Oded- Yeah i did, sorry being asking you again and again but still am confused. As i know running application from Process.start with parameters is as we run it from command prompt. let's say I have started the application using Process.Start but dont know how to pass the parameters, I mean desktop application accept parameters in which sequence/order.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @Muhammad - The MSDN documentation explains it all, with examples.